# Почему моргает меню?

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Не мог бы кто-нибудь глянуть верстку почему моргает меню:
адрес http://activities.ursmu.ru/, при наведении на пункт "ДУХОВНО-НРАВСТВЕННОЕ ВОСПИТАНИЕ" появляется всплывающее меню и оно постоянно моргает. Все стили перелопатил, не могу понять: почему оно моргает?

Comment: [mcve] должен быть в вопросе. Ссылки могут быть только дополнением

Comment: Google Chrome, и тоже не моргает

Comment: Chrome Windows моргает, даже нажать невозможно.

Comment: Добавляй непосредственно в вопрос, разметку, стили, и возможно js-скрипты, если они исползьзуются

Comment: у меня моргает, когда вожу курсором по всплывшем подменю. такое может быть в случае, если, например, прописано условие наведения и на открытие и на закрытие этого меню - тогда оно будет открываться при наведении и сразу закрывать и сразу открываться и...

Comment: Может проще кто-нибудь посмотрит верстку через плагин в браузере, чем вырезать оттуда что-то и составлять примеры.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема, из-за которой моргает раскрывающееся меню, состоит в следующем: раскрывающееся меню не является вложенным в основное меню (в структуре html)

Вы зарегистрировали событие `mousemove` на пункте основного меню, и пока мышь движется в его пределах, дополнительное меню отображается. Однако, как только вы наводите мышь на выпадающее меню (посмотрите картинку, и увидите область пересечения обоих меню) событие `mousemove` завершается и дополнительное меню скрывается (т.к. мышь уже **не** находится в пределах основного меню). После этого событие снова срабатывает (т.к. дополнительное меню уже скрыто и вы все еще находитесь в области пересечения) и ситуация повторяется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тогда почему вот здесь работает как надо: http://edu.ursmu.ru/

Comment: Там работает потому, что разработчик для отслеживания работы меню использует класс `active`, который при наведении добавляется и основному меню и выпадающему. Если вы  копируете чей-то код, то следует до конца понимать как он работает. Вообще ужасная реализация с кучей событий и всяких классов, вместо того чтобы использовать банальный `:hover`.

Comment: Я взял весь код оттуда и все равно моргает.

Comment: Открываете консоль (F12 в Google Chrome), открываете вкладку Elements и находите в коде ваше меню. Водите по нему и видите, что класс `.active` не добавляется. Делаете то же самое для сайта, где работает, и видите, что там этот класс добавляется при наведении. Это означает, что вы не все правильно скопировали.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что у вас `<div class="foold">` стоит вне тэга `<a>`
поставьте его внутрь тэга `<a href="http://fane.ursmu.ru">Духовно-нравственное воспитание</a>`
Или лучше используйте список `<ul>`

Comment: Тогда почему тут http://edu.ursmu.ru/ нормально работает? Все взято оттуда.

Comment: Наверное потому что там js-ом добавляется класс `.active` и меню и ссылке.